# What class to use for showing images in PyQt5

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now, but cannot seem to figure it out. I am developing a program with a UI that I made in `Qt Designer`, where I will be analyzing images using `cv2`. Part of this analysis involves having the user click on the image to store different coordinates from the image to be used later. When I made the UI in `Qt Designer`, the image object is of the class `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView`, but I cannot figure out how to show an image from `cv2`, which is a `numpy array` on an object of type `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView`. I am thinking I should be using a `QtGui.QPixmap`, but I'm still not sure. It seems there is not great documentation, so I'm having troubles figuring out how to choose how to represent these images that I plan to have interactions with and analysis of.

Comment: [QGraphicsPixmapItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html).

Answer (score 1):

I did end up using `QGraphicsPixmapItem` as suggested by ekhumoro in the comments. I also used `QImage` to do this though. An example of how I'm doing this is

```
image_window = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(centralwidget)
raw_image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
height, width, channel = image.shape
bytes_per_line = width * 3
image = QtGui.QImage(raw_image.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
image_window.setScene(scene)
```

And this worked great for me. There may still be some optimizations I can do, but it gives me the freedom to keep everything separated so I can easily do manipulations to the raw_image pixel matrix. I also have everything abstracted by having a class for the `scene` and `raw_image`.